# Displaying taxonomy name in template file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have single-property.php template file. And I want to display taxonomy name and value in that template file. This is my code in template file...

```
 $prop_category_array            =   get_the_terms($post->ID, 'property_category');

 if(isset($prop_category_array[0])){
     $prop_category_selected   =   $prop_category_array[0]->term_id;
 }

 $prop_action_category_array     =   get_the_terms($post->ID, 'property_action_category');
 if(isset($prop_action_category_array[0])){
    $prop_action_category_selected           =   $prop_action_category_array[0]->term_id;
 }
```

I want to display value in `$prop_category_selected` and `$prop_action_category_selected` .
This is the output for first array

```
Array ( [5] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 5 [name] => Agriculture Lands [slug] =>  
 agriculture-lands [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 5 [taxonomy] => property_category
[description] => Houses [parent] => 0 [count] => 9 [object_id] => 6915 [filter] => raw ) )
```

And this is output for second array

```
Array ( [150] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 150 [name] => Sales [slug] => sales [term_group] 
 => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 151 [taxonomy] => property_action_category [description] => Sales
 [parent] => 0 [count] => 9 [object_id] => 6915 [filter] => raw )
```

Comment: Where you want to display `$stop_category_selected`

Comment: In that template file just below above code.

Comment: Why can't you go with `print` or `echo` ..like `print $stop_category_selected;`

Comment: I tried that But it giving error undefined variable error

Comment: Check my answer below @Kedar B

Comment: Your code will never work. You cannot reference your array like that. The term I'd is used as index key, the array does not start at `0`. Be carefull of this

Comment: So there is nothing for `$prop_action_category_array[0]` and your array object clearly showing values for `$prop_action_category_array[150]` not for `[0]`

Comment: use like this `if(is_object($prop_action_category_array[150]))` check my updated answer @KedarB

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yes ofcourse it's hardcoding,  But she wants to print for specific objects so there is no need to loop unnecessary elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code ...

```
$property_category= strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'property_category', '', ', 
 ', '' ) );
$property_action_category= strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID,
'property_action_category', '', ', ', '' ) );

echo $property_category." and ".$property_action_category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$prop_category_array            =   get_the_terms($post->ID, 'property_category');

 if(is_object($prop_category_array[5])){
     $prop_category_selected   =   $prop_category_array[5]->term_id;
 }

 $prop_action_category_array     =   get_the_terms($post->ID, 'property_action_category');
 if(is_object($prop_action_category_array[150])){
    $prop_action_category_selected           =   $prop_action_category_array[150]->term_id;
 } 

 echo isset($prop_action_category_selected)?$prop_action_category_selected:'No value for variable  $prop_action_category_selected';
 echo isset($prop_category_selected)?$prop_category_selected:'No value for variable $prop_category_selected ';
```

I am not sure this is your expected answer you said getting undefined variable error so I am writing this. Just check once.

Comment: so there is no elements in this array `$prop_action_category_array` . so first check `var_dump($prop_action_category_array)` if array have the values then both variable assign with a value  `$prop_action_category_selected` and `$prop_category_selected`

Comment: When I print that array, it gives me correct values. I will show you print_r output.

Comment: can you paste the array here